# Bootstrap 4 and html : button toggle and modals

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-modal, navbar

I tried to make a login button which opens up a modal for login details. When I click on the button it is referred to that point where I want it to be. But nothing opens up. A similar problem is with another button that has to open up another modal.

My 2nd problem in about the navbar toggling action is not working. there is no response from the button when I click on the toggle button.

below is my code - :

### CODE FOR NAV BAR BUTTON -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" height="30" width="41"></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span>
                            Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html"><span
                                class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span> Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html"><span
                                class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg"></span> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="navbar-text">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#loginModal">
                        <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Login
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

-------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------
CODE FOR LOGIN MODAL - 
  <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="content">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        &times;
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputEmail3"
                                    placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1"
                                    id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                                    <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto"
                                data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>enter code here
    </div>
</body>

      ' <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
     <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"> 
                            </script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"> 
      </script>
  <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
     </script>
     <script>'$'(document).on('.data-api')</script>
    <script>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.navbar-toggler {bordeR:2px solid red !important;}
body{min-height: 500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-md">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" height="30" width="41"></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span>
                            Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html"><span
                                class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span> Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html"><span
                                class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg"></span> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="navbar-text">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
                        <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Login
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


  <div id="loginModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="content">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        &times;
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputEmail3"
                                    placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1"
                                    id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                                    <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

1. There is no Bootstrap JS and jQuery Added, so without it, modal will not work
2. do not pass href on login button, instead use `data-target="#loginModal"`
3. remove FADE class from modal,

I have removed many other classes from your code just for demo purpose, like fixed top on nav, yuou have have those as per your requirements

Comment: If this helped you, don't forget to mark it as right answer.